# if formula for two separate data groups

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I'm creating a recreational spreadsheet to keep track of my soccer league standings.

Here is my problem....

-A    ---------B-------------------C---------------D------------E-F-G--------H---I----J------K----L---M

H/A -----    OPP.    ----- GOALS FOR     GOALS AGAINST  W T L ----- HW HT HL --- AW AT AL

```
H      RED       4              2       1         ?
A      RED       1              3           1                      ?
```

I need a formula that will put the home result in the home column (as 1 for win, and blank for zero) and the same for the away result

basically,

=if(a4="h", and c4>d4,1,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout is unintelligible but interpreting "and the same for the away result" as required in a different column I'd suggest:

```
=IF(OR(AND($C4<$D4,B4<>"A"),AND($C4>$D4,B4="H")),1,"")
```

copied across one column and down to suit. (Does not cover draws.)

Answer (score 0):

This question really belongs in the superuser.com forum, but as it is simple:

```
=IF(AND(A4="h",C4>D4),1,0)
```